# Conditionally apply css based on the existence of a child element

Tags: css, less

Is it possible using **less** to do a conditional? The logic I want is if a table > tr > td has an `a` tag, then apply `padding: 20px` on the `a` tag. If there is no `a` tag in the `td`, then apply the padding on the `td` itself.

Comment: Less is just a css pre-processor. You will have to define rules to handle both the situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are suggesting is not possible in CSS so LESS won't be able to do it either.

However, we can try to be clever:

```
table > tr > td {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
table > tr > td a {
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

It looks weird and "hacky", but if i may, so does your request :)

Comment: That works. The point is so users can click the entire area inside of `a` table cells, not just the link. This requires applying padding on the `a` tag, not the `td`. But all `td` don't have `a` tags.

Comment: Then another solution would be the use of the immediate child operator: `>`. This would much more elegant: `table > tr > td > * {padding: 20px;}`